# Load URL from S3 into AVPlayer with security

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, avplayer, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to load a m3u8 file from an S3 bucket.
I need the S3 bucket to be secure, meaning my files can't be public.

I set up a pool id using Cognito to log in my user and only logged in user can access my S3 bucket.

My logged in user has an IAM role that should be able to read the url.

my IAM policy:

```
{
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListObjects",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucketByTags",
            "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
            "s3:GetBucketTagging",
            "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:ListBucketVersions",
            "s3:GetBucketLogging",
            "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
            "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
            "s3:GetObjectTagging",
            "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
            "s3:GetIpConfiguration",
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
            "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
            "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
            "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "s3:GetBucketNotification",
            "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
            "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
            "s3:GetBucketCORS",
            "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::S3_BUCKET"
    }
```

My Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::S3_BUCKET",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::IAM_AUTH_ROLE"
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

My swift code:

```
    let assetKeys = [
        "playable",
        "hasProtectedContent"
    ]

    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: AVAsset(url: url), automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: assetKeys)
    playerItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status), options: [.old, .new], context: nil)

    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController?.player = player
    playerViewController?.showsPlaybackControls = false

    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer?.frame = mediaView.layer.frame
    mediaView.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer!, at: 0)
```

I'm using this to retrieve the contents:

```
- (void)listAvailableContentsWithPrefix:(nullable NSString *)prefix
                             marker:(nullable NSString *)marker
                  completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<AWSContent *> * _Nullable contents, NSString * _Nullable marker, NSError * _Nullable error))completionHandler;
```

and this to get the URL:

```
- (void)getRemoteFileURLWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSURL  * _Nullable url, NSError  * _Nullable error))completionHandler;
```

When I retrieve my user session, it says I'm connected so I suppose the app is linked to AWS with the right IAM role when trying to access data

I do not know if the issue comes from my policies or if it comes from my AVPlayer?

Thank you